# Can I do parameter expansion and substitution without new variables in bash?

Tags: bash, parameters

I've seen many similar questions, but I couldn't work it out for me, relatively simple task.  I have a variable with ip:port value which I get within bash script, that I don't want to change but have to modify it in one of the statements without making new variable

```
ipp=192.168.10.35:12346
# I just need IP number with replaced .10. to .130. in sed statement 
ssh MyRouter "sed -i '/${ipp%%:*//10./130.}/d' /var/run/miniupnpd.leases"
```

This **sed** statement doesn't match properly.  My `$ipp` variable should be modified to `192.168.130.35` for this **sed** statement.  Is there any way to do it with parameter expansion/substitution?
Currently the contents of file is following:

```
#cat /var/run/miniupnpd.leases
TCP:12347:192.168.130.39:12347:1685388432:Backend_API
TCP:12346:192.168.130.39:12346:1685388432:Home_UI
TCP:12349:192.168.130.39:12349:1685388432:Syncthing
TCP:12367:192.168.130.33:12367:1685388466:Backend_API
TCP:12366:192.168.130.33:12366:1685388466:Home_UI
TCP:12369:192.168.130.33:12369:1685388466:Syncthing
TCP:12387:192.168.130.35:12387:1685388577:Backend_API
TCP:12386:192.168.130.35:12386:1685388578:Home_UI
TCP:12389:192.168.130.35:12389:1685388578:Syncthing
TCP:12377:192.168.130.34:12377:1685388708:Backend_API
TCP:12376:192.168.130.34:12376:1685388709:Home_UI
TCP:12379:192.168.130.34:12379:1685388709:Syncthing
```

after sed it should be:

```
#cat /var/run/miniupnpd.leases

TCP:12347:192.168.130.39:12347:1685388432:Backend_API
TCP:12346:192.168.130.39:12346:1685388432:Home_UI
TCP:12349:192.168.130.39:12349:1685388432:Syncthing
TCP:12367:192.168.130.33:12367:1685388466:Backend_API
TCP:12366:192.168.130.33:12366:1685388466:Home_UI
TCP:12369:192.168.130.33:12369:1685388466:Syncthing
TCP:12377:192.168.130.34:12377:1685388708:Backend_API
TCP:12376:192.168.130.34:12376:1685388709:Home_UI
TCP:12379:192.168.130.34:12379:1685388709:Syncthing
```

Comment: `without making new variable` Why? What is the cost of making a new variables?

Comment: I don't want to make new variables if I can change existing one for one time statement

Comment: What if there are two instances of `.10.` in `ipp`?

Comment: Thanks for notice @oguzismail I've modified `${ipp/.10./.130.}` and since it's private IP space then only one match can be found at maximum.

Comment: actually I would need to escape dots  so `${ipp/\.10\./\.130\.}`

Comment: Not directly. You can use a positional parameter instead of a named variable, but is that really different? `ssh ... host "bash -c 'sed -i /\${1/10./130.}/d filename' dummy ${ipp%%:}"` but no you don't need to backslash the dots; `${var/old/new}` is a shell 'pattern' like glob, not a regexp

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085.  Can you please explain  `{1` and `dummy` is it $1 treated as first parameter?

Comment: I got now working result with following statement `ssh MyRouter "sed -i '/$(echo ${ipp%%:*} | sed 's/\.10\./.130./g')/d' filename` which is relatively simple and understandable for my knowledge level.  Not sure if it can be done more compact or efficient

Comment: Please show content of `/var/run/miniupnpd.leases` and your desired content in your question.

Comment: @Cyrus I've updated the question to show how the file looks before and how it should be at the end

Comment: `ssh MyRouter sed -i "$( IFS=.: read a b _ d _ <<<$ipp; echo "'/:$a\.$b\.130\.$d:/d'" )" filename`

Comment: Denis: yes `${1}` is the first [positional parameter](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Positional-Parameters.html) (`${anypositiveintegern}` is the n'th) and [can be modified with - ? + % # / ^ , etc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) the same as a named variable. The simpler syntax `$1` can be used if there is no modification and the number is a single digit (1-9), and is much more common.

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085  I'm also not sure what "dummy" is (me? :).  I had to replace 'bash'  with 'sh' (openwrt -router), but it does not remove modified IP from the file.  Maybe you can formulate it as an Answer

Comment: Thanks @jhnc  This works.  How come there is no need for the quotes before 'sed' and after 'filename' needed.?  This can also be a good solution for me

Comment: `ssh` concatenates all its arguments into a single string and then feeds that to the remote shell, which then re-parses it. In my code above, the double-quotes are removed by the local shell before `ssh` sees it, and the single-quotes are removed by the remote shell.  But consider: `ssh localhost "echo '$(date +local)'" '"$(date +remote)"' \''$(date +ignored)'\'`

Comment: I think, in general, you can replace `ssh host` with `echo` to get an idea what the remote shell will see

Comment: Denis: no that was not an insult. The [syntax for -c](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html) uses the first argument after the script to set $0 and the rest for $1 $2 etc, so to get `${ipp%%:}` in $1 I need to pass a value for $0 that doesn't matter, hence is dummy. Some folks use a (somewhat) meaningful value here, like anonscript or commandline. This part should work for any POSIX shell but the `${.../old/new}` part may not; you could try swapping to do that part on the outside (the ssh sender) and the ${...%%:} part on the inside (openwrt)

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085  I got it now, also I spotted why it didn't work for me `{ipp##:*}`  (asterix was missing)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085  I tried also with $0 and it worked so I could omit extra parameter.  Not sure if this is expected behavior or just a coincidence `ssh host "bash -c 'sed -i /\${0/10./130.}/d filename' ${ipp%%:*}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, thanks to many comments I was able to solve my problem in a few ways
as @dave_thompson_85 suggested (with added * to remove port, and . to make sure of the match) with using positional argument rather than new variable.

```
ssh MyRouter "bash -c 'sed -i /\${1/.10./.130.}/d /var/run/miniupnpd.leases' dummy ${ipp%%:*}"
```

or as @jhnc suggested to read new variables

```
ssh MyRouter sed -i "$( IFS=.: read a b _ d _ <<<$ipp; echo "'/:$a\.$b\.130\.$d:/d'" )" /var/run/miniupnpd.leases
```

or using piped sed

```
ssh MyRouter "sed -i '/$(echo ${ipp%%:*} | sed 's/.10./.130./g')/d' /var/run/miniupnpd.leases
```

They all give me correct result of removing entries of the modified IP number

```
ipp=192.168.10.35:12346
ssh MyRouter "bash -c 'sed /\${1/.10./.130.}/d /var/run/miniupnpd.leases' dummy ${ipp%%:*}"

TCP:12347:192.168.130.39:12347:1685388432:Backend_API
TCP:12346:192.168.130.39:12346:1685388432:Home_UI
TCP:12349:192.168.130.39:12349:1685388432:Syncthing
TCP:12367:192.168.130.33:12367:1685388466:Backend_API
TCP:12366:192.168.130.33:12366:1685388466:Home_UI
TCP:12369:192.168.130.33:12369:1685388466:Syncthing
TCP:12377:192.168.130.34:12377:1685388708:Backend_API
TCP:12376:192.168.130.34:12376:1685388709:Home_UI
TCP:12379:192.168.130.34:12379:1685388709:Syncthing
```